# Автоматическое добавление fk-ключа во вторую таблицу при создании новой строки в первой таблице

Tags: django, postgresql, django-model

Как реализовать автоматическое добавление Fk-ключа в таблицу "Booked" при создании новой строки данных в таблице "Request"? я использую Django.

```
class Booked(models.Model):
booking_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
request_id = models.ForeignKey('Request', models.CASCADE, db_column='request_id')

class Request(models.Model):
    request_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая функция в классе Request решила вопрос

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_Booked(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Booked.objects.create(request_id_id=instance.request_id)


post_save.connect(create_Booked, sender=Request)
```